# Can't insert a string variable inside a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so I am trying to insert a dynamical data inside a row. This is most likely not the best way to do it, but after banging my head on the wall for hours I still can't understand why the `$insert` string won't get queried by `mysql_query`. Even when I `echo` it and copy what is echoed to the query it works, but querying the variable doesn't.

```
$insert = '"INSERT INTO '.$_SESSION['tabsel'].' (';
echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "Enter ".$row[0]." <input type='text' name='data[]'>";
    echo "<br>";
    $insert .= $row[0].",";
    $_SESSION['insert'] = $insert;
}

echo "<input type='submit' value='Add'>";
echo "</form>";
if(isset($_POST['data']))
{
    $insert = $_SESSION['insert'];
    $strlength = strlen($insert);
    $insert = substr($insert,0,($strlength-1));
    $insert .= " VALUES (";
    foreach($_POST['data'] as $value)
    {
        $insert .= "'$value',";
        $_SESSION['insert'] = $insert;
    }
}

$insert = $_SESSION['insert'];
$strlength = strlen($insert);
$insert = substr($insert,0,($strlength-1));
$insert .= ')"';
$_SESSION['insert'] = $insert;
$insert = $_SESSION['insert'];
echo $insert."<br>";
$seldb = mysql_select_db($_SESSION['sel']);
if($seldb && (!empty($_POST['data'])) && (isset($_SESSION['sel'])) && (isset($_SESSION['tabsel'])))
{
    $insert = $_SESSION['insert'];
    echo $insert;
    $query = mysql_query($insert, $con);
    if($query)
    {
        echo "Record succesfully added!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
}
```

Error given:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `"INSERT INTO mtable (id,nr,d,ra) VALUES ('d','d','d','d')"` at line 1

Comment: What about also posting the echo'd string? And there is not `mysql_query` in your code.

Comment: "INSERT INTO druga (id,podaci,d,ra) VALUES ('d','d','d','d')" The query is next line :) P.S. Error is You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"INSERT INTO druga (id,podaci,d,ra) VALUES ('d','d','d','d')"' at line 1

Comment: **Do not pass unfiltered user input to SQL**. The `mysql_` functions are being deprecated, you should be using `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead, and use bind variables to pass user input to the query. (Also, I don't actually see any calls to `mysql_query` in the code you posted.)

Comment: $query=mysql_query($insert, $con);
       if($query)
       {
        echo "Record succesfully added!";
       }
       else
       { 
        echo mysql_error();
       }
       }

Comment: @user1364022, edit your answer and put things in comments.

Comment: The problem with this particular query is that you're including a literal `"` before `INSERT`. But my earlier comment about `PDO` and bind variables still stands.

Comment: @DCoder: I suggest you post that as an answer :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include a PHP variable inside a mysql insert statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-insert-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the echo'd string

```
"INSERT INTO druga (id,podaci,d,ra) VALUES ('d','d','d','d')"
```

You need to remove the leading and trailing quote characters you are placing in the SQL query. Modify these two lines of code:

- Remove the leading quote character.

  ```
  $insert='INSERT INTO '.$_SESSION['tabsel'].' (';
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  $insert='"INSERT INTO '.$_SESSION['tabsel'].' (';
  ```
- Remove the trailing quote character.

  ```
  $insert.=')';
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  $insert.=')"';
  ```

Comment: Aha, first time here :) Done!